# Parsing HTML text that isn't labeled

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm making a spreadsheet from the html of a website.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to pull the information on unlabeled data.  For example, I could write a program to search for text that is within a `<span class="city-names">` to find the city that the university is in, but the name of the university, *St. Petersburg State University*, has no such tag.  Is there a way for me to, using Python and BeautifulSoup, to identify this as the university (like by identifying that it's the second instance of unlabeled text)?

Thank you!

```html
<div class="result" style="width:100%;">
  <span class="uppercase bold country-name" style="width:100%;">
        Russia
        <span class="city-names">
         St. Petersburg
        </span>
  </span>
  <br/>
  <span class="bold">
        <a href="http://eap.ucop.edu/OurPrograms/russia/Pages/russian_area_studies_st_petersburg.aspx" target="_blank">
         Russian Area Studies, St. Petersburg - Fall
        </a>
       </span>
  <br/>Council on International Educational Exchange, St. Petersburg
  <br/>St. Petersburg State University
</div>
```

Comment: Can you assume the university will always be after a second line break `<br>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit crude, is this what you intend to do?

Try if this works with the whole page.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="result" style="width:100%;">
  <span class="uppercase bold country-name" style="width:100%;">
        Russia
        <span class="city-names">
         St. Petersburg
        </span>
  </span>
  <br/>
  <span class="bold">
    <a href="http://eap.ucop.edu/OurPrograms/russia/Pages/russian_area_studies_st_petersburg.aspx" target="_blank">
        Russian Area Studies, St. Petersburg - Fall
    </a>
  </span>
  <br/>Council on International Educational Exchange, St. Petersburg
  <br/>St. Petersburg State University
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
cities = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'result'})
for city in cities:
    spans = city.find_all('span')
    for span in spans:
        span.decompose()
    text_you_need = BeautifulSoup(str(city),"html.parser").find('div').text
    university = text_you_need.strip().split('\n')[1].strip()
    print(university)
```

I removed the span tags' contents from the div and got the second line of text and did a strip().

output:

```
St. Petersburg State University
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use find_all function if you know it always comes in the specific position. For the example you provided,

```
 span = soup.div.find_all('span')[2]
```

will point the span tag with the university name.